# Block adware injectors from my site (especially IE and Firefox)

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, azure, bots, spyware

I have a single page web application hosted on `Windows Azure` My site is very prone to adware (mainly on `IE` and sometimes on `Firefox`). I notice more popular sites are not as prone to these attacks. How can I make my site less prone to `Ad Injectors`? My site is of course hosted in the cloud giving me very little access to server related settings. Would hosting on a dedicated server help (and what would I need to install on the server)? Can this issue be resolved via certain `js` libraries?

Unfortunately not much has been said about this subject. [This](http://ask.metafilter.com/197890/Im-going-to-war-with-a-Level-84-Adware-Injector-help-me-destroy-it) is about the only page I found discussing it. Would installing `SSL` eliminate the problem?

Your help is appreciated. Thanks!